# Using quotation marks inside quotation marks

Tags: python, syntax, string-literals, quoting

When I want to do a `print` command in Python and I need to use quotation marks, I don't know how to do it without closing the string.

For instance:

```
print " "a word that needs quotation marks" "
```

But when I try to do what I did above, I end up closing the string and I can't put the word I need between quotation marks.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You could do this in one of three ways:

1. Use single and double quotes together:

   ```
   print('"A word that needs quotation marks"')
   "A word that needs quotation marks"
   ```
2. Escape the double quotes within the string:

   ```
   print("\"A word that needs quotation marks\"")
   "A word that needs quotation marks"
   ```
3. Use triple-quoted strings:

   ```
   print(""" "A word that needs quotation marks" """)
   "A word that needs quotation marks"
   ```

Comment: Escaping the double-quotes works, but the extra spaces you've put in are now part of the string, easily fixed by getting rid of the spaces.

Similarly with triple-quoted strings - the extra spaces become part of the string, and I'm not sure how to fix this as putting the inner " next to the triple-" causes a SyntaxError

Comment: You can avoid the SyntaxError by using single triple quotes: '''"a word"''', but now things are getting silly..

Comment: If you have several words like this which you want to concatenate, I would use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51020790/5608610). There is also a Python 3.6 specific answer given which is very readable.

Comment: 4) `print('\'A word that needs quotation marks\'')`

Answer (score 20):

You need to escape it.

```
>>> print("The boy said \"Hello!\" to the girl")
The boy said "Hello!" to the girl
>>> print('Her name\'s Jenny.')
Her name's Jenny.
```

See the python page for [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 7):

Python accepts both " and ' as quote marks, so you could do this as:

```
>>> print '"A word that needs quotation marks"'
"A word that needs quotation marks"
```

Alternatively, just escape the inner "s

```
>>> print "\"A word that needs quotation marks\""
"A word that needs quotation marks"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the literal escape character `\`

```
print("Here is, \"a quote\"")
```

The character basically means *ignore the semantic context of my next charcter, and deal with it in its literal sense*.

Answer (score 2):

When you have several words like this which you want to concatenate in a string, I recommend using `format` or `f-strings` which increase readability dramatically (in my opinion).

To give an example:

```
s = "a word that needs quotation marks"
s2 = "another word"
```

Now you can do

```
print('"{}" and "{}"'.format(s, s2))
```

which will print

```
"a word that needs quotation marks" and "another word"
```

As of Python 3.6 you can use:

```
print(f'"{s}" and "{s2}"')
```

yielding the same output.

Answer (score 1):

One case which is prevalent in duplicates is the requirement to use quotes for external processes.  A workaround for that is to not use a shell, which removes the requirement for one level of quoting.

```
os.system("""awk '/foo/ { print "bar" }' %""" % filename)
```

can usefully be replaced with

```
subprocess.call(['awk', '/foo/ { print "bar" }', filename])
```

(which also fixes the bug that shell metacharacters in `filename` would need to be escaped from the shell, which the original code failed to do; but without a shell, no need for that).

Of course, in the vast majority of cases, you don't want or need an external process at all.

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if 'foo' in line:
            print("bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3.2.2 on Windows,

```
print(""""A word that needs quotation marks" """)
```

is ok. I think it is the enhancement of Python interpretor.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try string addition:
`print " "+'"'+'a word that needs quotation marks'+'"'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned *[explicit conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)* yet

```
>>> print('{!r}'.format('a word that needs quotation marks'))
'a word that needs quotation marks'
```

The flag `!r` is a shorthand of the `repr()` built-in function<sup>1</sup>. It is used to print the object representation  `object.__repr__()` instead of `object.__str__()`.

There is an interesting *side-effect* though:

```
>>> print("{!r} \t {!r} \t {!r} \t {!r}".format("Buzz'", 'Buzz"', "Buzz", 'Buzz'))
"Buzz'"      'Buzz"'     'Buzz'      'Buzz'
```

Notice how different composition of quotation marks are handled differenty so that it fits a valid string representation of a Python object <sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 Correct me if anybody knows otherwise.</sup>

<sup>2 The question's original example `" "word" "` is not a valid representation in Python</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in IDLE Python 3.8.2

```
print('''"A word with quotation marks"''')
```

Triple single quotes seem to allow you to include your double quotes as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose in single quotes like

```
print '"a word that needs quotation marks"'
```

Or Enclose in Double quotes

```
print "'a word that needs quotation marks'"
```

Or Use backslash \ to Escape

```
print " \"a word that needs quotation marks\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use escape characters and actually want to print quote without saying `"` or `\"` and so on, you can tell python to print the ASCII value of the `"` character.
The quote character in ASCII is 34, (single quote is 39)

In python 3

```py
print(f'{chr(34)}')
```

Output:
`"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).