# Why is there a need for the escape character '\'' in C?

Tags: c

Im just curious why there is a need to escape a single quote character when you could actually print a single quote in the printf function without having the need to escape it.

Comment: In printf, you can print `'` without or with escaping. But for single character `'`, you need to escape it.

Comment: `printf("%c\n", ''');` is invalid.(`empty character constant`and extra `'`) this should be `printf("%c\n", '\'');` but simply `printf("'\n");` is valid.

Comment: On the other hand (and to the OP's defense), other languages can do without an escape character: [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/python-using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks), [VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba). Then again, since in C you already need an escape for several other purposes, it's just easier to tack this on, rather than to invent explicit (other) rules for quotes only.

Comment: It's the same the other way round: You must escape `"` in string literals but not in character constants, `"\""`, `'"'`, `'\"'` are all valid, but `"""` is not.

Comment: You have a great point there.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To allow for character initializations like this:

```
char quote = '\'';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed a `"` in a string or have a character like `'`, you need to escape.

You can workaround this if you only intend to use `printf()`, but for general use, you might want to need both.

For example, you might want to send the string `I said "hello"` via a socket connection, or write it into a file, then you'd have to make ugly hacks because you are restricted if you couldn't do so.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to compare a character value with single quote. In this case you need something like `if(c == '\'')`.