# PYTHON - Using double quotes in SQL constant

Tags: sql, python-3.x, db2

I have a SQL query entered into a constant. One of the fields that I need to put in my where clause is USER which is a key word. To run the query I put the keyword into double quotes.

I have tried all of the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/python-using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks) yet none seem to be working.

Here is what I have for my constant:

```
SELECT_USER_SECURITY = "SELECT * FROM USER_SECURITY_TRANSLATED WHERE \"USER\" = '{user}' and COMPANY = " \
                       "'company_number'  and TYPE NOT IN (1, 4)"
```

I am not sure how to get this query to work from my constant.

I also tried wrapping the whole query in """. I am getting a key error on the USER.

```
SELECT_USER_SECURITY = """SELECT * FROM USER_SECURITY_TRANSLATED WHERE "USER" = '{user}' and
                          COMPANY = 'company_number'  and TYPE NOT IN (1, 4)"""
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
nose.proxy.KeyError: 'user'
```

Comment: "None seem to be working" sounds a bit too broad. Care to post the actual error message(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the triple quoted solution was the best one. The problem I was running into was I had not included the "user" key in my dictionary of params which formatted the query.