# How to incorporate quotation marks into a user input?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
def palindrome(s):
    s=input ("Enter a phrase (**use quotation marks for words**): ")
    s.lower()
    return s[::-1]==s

palindrome(s)
```

This is my code. How do I change it so I can take out the bolded section? I use python 2 and it won't accept string inputs without the quotation marks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/python-using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `input()`?  Try using `raw_input()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input`. In Python 2 `input` tries to evaluate the user's input, so letters are evaluated as variables.

Answer (score 1):

A `raw_input` will do the job. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/5018771) about input differences in Python 2 and 3 might help you.

Besides, I think the parameter `s` is not necessary. And `s.lower()` alone does not change the value of `s`.

```
def palindrome():
    s = raw_input("Enter a phrase : ")
    s = s.lower()
    return s[::-1] == s

palindrome()
```

Comment: Another thing, so the raw_input makes it considered like a string? And also I used the s.lower because when I tried to run "Eat Tae", it wouldsay it wasn't a palindrome. How do I solve this?

Comment: Yes, unlike `input`, in Python 2 `raw_input` does not try to evaluate what you write, and takes it as a string. So you don't need quotes and it works. For `lower`, just calling `s.lower()` returns a string that corresponds to `s` with all lowercase characters. But it is not automatically stored in `s`. Therefore you have to do `s = s.lower()`