# Invalid syntax - Expression returning a string in f-String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, f-string

I'm loving the new f-Strings in python 3.6, but I'm seeing a couple issues when trying to return a String in the expression.
The following code doesn't work and tells me I'm using invalid syntax, even though the expression itself is correct.

```
print(f'{v1} is {'greater' if v1 > v2 else 'less'} than {v2}') # Boo error
```

It tells me that `'greater'` and `'less'` are unexpected tokens. If I replace them with two variables containing the strings, or even two integers, the error disappears.

```
print(f'{v1} is {10 if v1 > v2 else 5} than {v2}') # Yay no error
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The syntax highlighting in your editor or even here on StackOverflow is a clue as well :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Syntax when F' string dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876137/invalid-syntax-when-f-string-dictionary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must still respect rules regarding [quotes within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks):

```
v1 = 5
v2 = 6

print(f'{v1} is {"greater" if v1 > v2 else "less"} than {v2}')

# 5 is less than 6
```

Or possibly more readable:

```
print(f"{v1} is {'greater' if v1 > v2 else 'less'} than {v2}")
```

Note that regular strings permit `\'`, i.e. use of the backslash for quotes within quotes. This is not permitted in f-strings, [as noted in PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification):

> Backslashes may not appear anywhere within expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Just mix the quotes, check *howto* [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
print(f'{v1} is {"greater" if v1 > v2 else "less"} than {v2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks cause the error.

Use this:

```
print(f'{v1} is {"greater" if v1 > v2 else "less"} than {v2}')
```