# Invalid Syntax when F' string dictionary

Tags: python

When I try to f'string dictionary, it says invalid syntax.

```
def up_low(s):
    d={"upper":0,"lower":0}
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            d["upper"]+=1
            print (f"No. of Upper case characters: {d["upper"]}")
        elif c.islower():
            d["lower"]+=1
            print (f"No. of Lower case characters:{d["lower"]}")
        else:
            pass
```

it says invalid syntax for line 6 and line 9.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes for your key, like `d['upper']`. The string in which that appears is already in double quotes, so they are in conflict. You could also do the reverse, by single quoting the string instead, but I prefer the single quotes around the key.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `"` in a string enclosed with `"`, either use `'`, or enclose the string in `'`:

```
f"No. of Upper case characters: {d['upper']}"
```

Or:

```
f'No. of Upper case characters: {d["upper"]}'
```

Comment: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Answer (score 0):

Change your double quotes to single quotes inside `{d["upper"]}`

Here is full working code:

```
def up_low(s):
    d={"upper":0,"lower":0}
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            d["upper"]+=1
            print (f"No. of Upper case characters: {d['upper']}")
        elif c.islower():
            d["lower"]+=1
            print (f"No. of Lower case characters:{d['lower']}")
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any "other" string delimiter - even the triple ones:

```
d = {"k":"hello"}
print(f'''{d["k"]}''')
print(f"""{d["k"]}""")
print(f'{d["k"]}')
print(f"{d['k']}")
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Using the same ones confuses python - it does not know where the f-string ends and your key-string starts if you use the same delimiters.