# Invalid syntax error when using f-string in Python 3.6

Tags: python, f-string

I've run into this weird error and I'm wondering whether anyone has a clue what's going on.

I'm trying to print the minimal date from a date column in Pandas series. However, the following is raising an invalid syntax error:

`print(f'{df_raw['POSTING_DATE'].min()}')`

This does work, though:

```
min_date = df_raw['POSTING_DATE'].min()
print(f'{min_date}')
```

Using `.format()` also works. Obviously I can use a workaround here but I was just wondering why the f-string syntax doesn't work in this case. I thought the f-strings should be able to handle similar expressions.
I'm using Python 3.6.9.

Comment: It must be `print(f"{df_raw['POSTING_DATE'].min()}")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Syntax when F' string dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876137/invalid-syntax-when-f-string-dictionary)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609639/invalid-syntax-expression-returning-a-string-in-f-string

Answer (score 4):

Use `"` as:

```
print(f"{df_raw['POSTING_DATE'].min()}")
```

Update:

Ideally, we could use `\` to escape quotes but `f-strings` does not support using `\` in it so this wouldn't work with `f-strings`

```
print(f'{df_raw[\'POSTING_DATE\'].min()}')
```

Comment: Your first suggestion will not work. You can't escape quotes inside an f-string expression.

Comment: Yes, I realized after posting, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ooooh so that's what it was. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!