# Why does the Syntaxerror f-string: expecting '}' happening in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is where the error happened

```py
print(f'Hey, {Username}, your password is {'*' * Password}. The password is **{len(Password)}** long.')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid syntax - Expression returning a string in f-String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609639/invalid-syntax-expression-returning-a-string-in-f-string)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using single quote for main string as well as `'*'`.

Python interprets it as -

```
print( f'Hey, {Username}, your password is {'# string ends here.
*' * Password}. The password is **{len(Password)}** long.')
```

The last bracket goes unmatched and hence the error.

A quick fix would be to use double quotes in one of the strings.

```py
print(f'Hey, {Username}, your password is {"*" * Password}. The password is **{len(Password)}** long.')
```