# Datetime comparison using f strings in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, f-string

Consider the following dataframe

```
Y = pd.DataFrame([("2021-10-11","john"),("2021-10-12","wick")],columns = ['Date','Name'])
Y['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Y['Date'])
```

Now consider the following code snippet in which I try to print slices of the dataframe filtered on the column "Date". However, it prints a empty dataframe

```
for date in set(Y['Date']):
    print(Y.query(f'Date == {date.date()}'))
```

Essentially, I wanted to filter the dataframe on the column "Date" and do some processing on that in the loop. How do I achieve that?

Comment: What do you want to do and how do you want to filter the dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date needs to be accessed at the following query command:

```
Y = pd.DataFrame([("2021-10-11","john"),("2021-10-12","wick")],columns = ['Date','Name'])
for date in set(Y['Date']):
    print(Y.query('Date == @date'))
```

Comment: what is the need to define "date_to_be_queried"?

Comment: its an artifact of the implementation, its removed thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `""` because f-strings removed original `""` and error is raised:

```
Y = pd.DataFrame([("2021-10-11","john"),("2021-10-12","wick")],columns = ['Date','Name'])

Y['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Y['Date'])


for date in set(Y['Date']):
    print(Y.query(f'Date == "{date}"'))
```

Comment: why does repr return a string representation that is comparable? just curious.

Comment: @dineshdileep - checked again and change solution by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609728/2901002)