# How to do nothing in conditional statement while Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

Here is the thing:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
i = [x if x == 2 else "I don't need that!" for x in lst]
print(i)
```

Output:

```
["I don't need this item!", 2, "I don't need this item!"]
```

As you can see in output I have the first and last items which I want to not have.

I tried various things, such as to remove `else` statement (it's not possible), replace `0` with `pass` statement (it's not working either).

Is it even possible to get just needed items in `list` with conditionals while `list` comprehensions? Or it's only possible with `filter` function?

**Needed output:**

```
[2]
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: just drop the `else` part of your `if` statement: `[x for x in lst  if x == 2]`.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani question post has been updated.

Comment: If you must add something, you can try `pass` or `continue`

Comment: your "needed output" is the exact output you said you didnt want to have.. might want to check that

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It's cause error: `i = [x if x == 2 for x in lst]` SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @yatu fixed that right after i noticed... thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]
i = [x for x in lst if x == 2]
print(i)
```

Output:

```py
[2]
```

You haven´t used list comprehension correctly, the `if` statement should come after the `for` loop. See [list comprehensions in Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=list+comprehension+python&t=hp&ia=web) or [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more information.

Before the quetions had been changed, this was the answer:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]
i = [x if x == 2 else "I don't need this item!" for x in lst]
print(i)
```

Output:

```py
["I don't need this item!", 2, "I don't need this item!"]
```

[Quotation marks inside a string, explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 3):

You are putting the `if` in the wrong place. Try this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
i = [x for x in lst if x == 2]
print(i)
# [2]
```

Comment: Why downvoted? This is literally the same as the *edited version* of the accepted answer, except that the *edits* were not there when I wrote it... if anything, one could say my answer *inspired* the accepted one...

Comment: This is correct. Norok2 shows here that in the case of no else, the format for list comprehensions is a bit different -- the "if" goes at the end.