# drop quotes from list python3

Tags: python, list

IM Creating list of str.
how can remove the " in the list please?

```
['xxxxx', '', 'bb', "'errrr'"]
```

output desired:

```
 ['xxxxx', '', 'bb', 'errrr']
```

thank you

Comment: You don't want to drop the quotes from the list, but from an *element* of the list. How did the list get produced in the first place? For this specific example, `yourlist[3] = yourlist[3].strip("'")` would work

Comment: Why do you want to del the `"`?If you want to get the string element in the List,just use index to get the element,and it wouldn't show `"` and `'`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can `replace()` or `strip()` the single quote `'`

```py
your_list = [s.replace("\'", "") for s in your_list]
your_list = [s.strip("\'", "") for s in your_list]

# e.g 
your_list = [s.replace("\'", "") for s in ['xxxxx', '', 'bb', "'errrr'"]]
```

Double quotes appear in `print()` because you have single quotes `'` in one of your list elements

Example of the element is on 3rd position : `'errrr'`.

Or if you want to strip double quotes `"` as well

```py
your_list = [ s.strip("\'\"") for s in your_list]`
your_list = [ s.strip("\'\"") for s in ['xxxxx', '', '"bb"', "'errrr'"]]
print(your_list)
> ['xxxxx', '', 'bb', 'errrr']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(your list name) = [i.replace("\'", '') for i in (your list name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is related to your `'` charcter from the string

you may see [Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks)

for your example you can use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method:

```
l = ['xxxxx', '', 'bb', "'errrr'"]
l[3] = l[3].replace("'", '')
l
```

output:

```
['xxxxx', '', 'bb', 'errrr']
```

or you can use [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
l[3] = l[3].strip("'")
```