# Selenium does not run a javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrollbar, execute-script

I'm trying to execute a simple java script command at selenium using python for scroll a part of a web page.

Here's the code:

```
command_js = 'document.querySelector(' + "'" + 'css_div_example[css_example="this is just a example for css selector"]' + "').scroll(0, 10000)"
#string joined "document.querySelector('css_div_example[css_example="this is just a example for css selector"]').scroll(0, 10000)"
driver.execute_script(command_js)
```

Picture:

[Picture of scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnVs6.png)

**OBS.:**

- I tried to execute directly from Firefox console and it worked very well.
- Selenium does not return any error, just not execute it.
- I tried to WebDriverWait with EC and time.sleep().
- I am using python 3+ and PyCharm IDE, Firefox webdrivers...

**Anyone can help me?**

Comment: Can't you just tell selenium to select something down on that div?

Comment: Contents of the div just appears if scroll down the bar :/

>pt-br: Então, os elementos da div só aparecem quando scrolla a barra, até consigo pegar os primeiros elementos, mas nem sempre vai ser o que preciso...

Comment: You're switching around quotes there... not sure of syntax for python, but it doesn't look right.  You might need escape character... check here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks

Comment: You dont need to see the element to select it. You can use: driver.find_element_by_xpath()

Comment: Podemos ir de ptbr se preferir. Você clica com o botão direito no elemento que quer que o selenium selecione e escolha "inspecionar". Depois clica na parte do código que tem o elemento e escolha: "copy > copy Xpath". Você vai copiar algo semelhante à: //*[@id="description"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/th e colar dentro do "find_element_by_xpath()" no seu código. Dá para usar outros elementos de css e dom para selecionar.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação:
https://www.selenium.dev/pt-br/documentation/support_packages/working_with_select_elements/

Comment: @RafaelBraga Muito obrigado, usando o xpath consegui selecionar os elementos que eu queria.
Valeu pelo seu tempo!