# add each element in **quotes** to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to solve this

```
my_list = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

my_string = "They call me "
```

I would like to **iterate** in the list and print each element of the list in quotes at the end of the string.

something like this:

```
They call me "foo"
They call me "bar"
They call me "baz"
```

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use raw strings, `repr` is the function used to convert a string to raw string.

```
my_list = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

my_string = "They call me "

for i in my_list:
    print(my_string,repr(i))
```

output:

```
They call me  'foo'
They call me  'bar'
They call me  'baz'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution.

```
for s in my_list:
    print(f"They call me \"{s}\"")
```

Alternatively, to use the my_string variable,

```
for s in my_list:
    print(f"{my_string}\"{s}\"")
```

Comment: You can nest double quotes inside single quotes and the backslashes wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I'm aware, but I find that this practice makes for confusing code.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see your reasoning although even the [Black code formatter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#strings), which converts all single quotes strings to double quoted ones, will convert them to single quoted if they contain a backslash double quote due to less special character usage. Which also results in a smaller line length And I agree with this reasoning

Comment: @Jab That interesting. Personally, I'm in the habit of using single-quotes for characters (that is, one-character strings) and double quotes in all other cases.

Comment: @BenGrossmann It's because of things like this that make python difficult to understand or difficult to conform to it's code styling, it is so flexible that there's many ways to do things, it makes sense why many other languages (strongly typed ones in specific) have very specific ways of doing things. It makes reading code easier.

Comment: Thank you @BenGrossmann ! I'll go with the second solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use **f-strings**.

```py
my_list = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
my_string = " They call me "
for i in my_list:
    print(f'{my_string}"{i}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **double quotes** inside with **single quote** outside in line 1.

```
my_list = ['"foo"', '"bar"', '"baz"']
my_string = "They call me "
for i in my_list:
    print(f'{my_string}{i}')
```